# Series default assumptions?

Tags: complex, series-expansion, assumptions

I have a question about the "Series" command. Specifically, the following input

```
Series[Sqrt[x^2], {x, 0, 2}]
```

gives me the following output

```
x+O[x]^3.
```

However, we know that this is not true for some $x$, e.g. for $x<0$. Because of the singular derivative at $x=0$, I would have expected Mathematica to give an error of some kind here. Moreover, when adding an assumption like this

```
Series[Sqrt[x^2], {x, 0, 2}, Assumptions -> (x < 0)],
```

I still get the same output

```
x+O[x]^3,
```

whereas I know that the leading order should be $-x$ rather than $x$.

I am trying to understand why Mathematica gives me this result. Does "Series" somehow make some general assumptions about the variable of the expansion?

EDIT: I am using Mathematica version 10.2.

Comment: OK in Mma 11.1.0.0: the output under the assumption $x<0$ is $-x+O\left(x^3\right) $.

Comment: What version are you using?  Recent versions appear to give sensible answers.

Comment: Edited the question, I am using version 10.2. Is this is a bug in this version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an extended comment to demonstrate the effect of `Assumptions` in version 11.1.1  **While a problem exists in some earlier versions, it has been corrected.**

```
$Version

"11.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)"

Series[Sqrt[x^2], {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

```
Series[Sqrt[x^2], {x, 0, 2}, Assumptions -> (x > 0)]
```

[image]

```
Series[Sqrt[x^2], {x, 0, 2}, Assumptions -> (x < 0)]
```

[image]

The last two are special cases of

```
Series[Sqrt[x^2], {x, 0, 2}, Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]
```

[image]

Comment: This seems more like an output I would have expected. I am using version 10.2, was this a bug in that version?

Comment: Yes, this appears to be a bug in (some?) earlier versions (e.g., it gives the result shown for `x > 0` in all four cases using v10.4.1 on my Mac).

Comment: Cool, that's clear then. Could you add to your answer that there's this bug in some earlier versions? I'll accept the answer then since that answers my question

Answer (score 1):

Bob Hanlon has shown which solution Mathematica 11.1.1 has determined. We can check it with the Taylor formula.

```
s = Sum[1/j! Nest[(x - x0)*# &, D[Sqrt[x^2], {x, j}] /. x -> x0, j], {j, 0, 2}]
```

((x - x0) x0)/Sqrt[x0^2] + Sqrt[x0^2]

```
Limit[s, x0 -> 0, Direction -> -1]
x

Limit[s, x0 -> 0, Direction -> 1]
-x
```

Mathematica is right.

Comment: I am using version 10.2, which gave me the output in my question. Guess that version was bugged then? The command "Limit" does give the right result in 10.2 as well though.